# Homomorphisms from the group $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ to the additive group of rationals $\mathbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> There are $n$ homomorphisms from the group $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ to the additive group of rationals $\mathbb Q$.

how can i find that the above statement is true/false

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Elements of $\mathbb{Q}$ apart from the identity have infinite order, and all elements of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ have finite order. Can a group homomorphism map an element of finite order to an element which does not have finite order?

Answer (score 2):

Say the image of $1\in \mathbb Z_n$ is $x\in \mathbb Q$. Then $nx=0$ in the rationals, so $x=0$. Thus all homomorphisms are trivial, all elements are sent to $0$.